# How to update records in a table to trim whitespaces in JSON datatype of Postgres for a specific field

Tags: postgresql

I have a requirement to update a table by `TRIM` whitespace for a specific column which is a JSON datatype.

In the screenshot is the data structure of the table and the column I have to update is `SCOPE`

[image: Example of table structure]

Inside `SCOPE` I have to `TRIM` the field `SITES` and as example a screenshot of the testing table

[image: data records]

In the above screenshots, I have to TRIM only sites using an update as I need to build a migration function which for every row will TRIM from SITES the white spaces.

I have no clue in `JSONB` type how to do it.

UPDATE screenshot of the leading whitespace in data
[image: white space in data]

Comment: 1) I am not seeing any whitespace, probably because -> 2) From here [JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html), "By contrast, jsonb does not preserve white space, does not preserve the order of object keys, and does not keep duplicate object keys.".

Comment: 1) in this data no but my supervisor told me to change all tables plus this one to TRIM white spaces maybe he didn't check this table. I never used JSONB so I didn't know. The issue was reported to me by the supervisor.

2) So I don't need to do anything on this JSONB means even a data record has space leading/trailing spaces are not persisted then

Comment: It comes down to what white spaces they are talking about? You can make whitespace significant by doing: `select '{" leading": 1, "trailing ": 2}'::jsonb; {" leading": 1, "trailing ": 2}`.  If that is the case then and you want to get rid of them, then you will need to walk through the JSON and deal with each element. If so do you need to deal with both the keys and the values?

Comment: I mean what is in the screenshot I was told we can have data looking like this `{"sites": [" 1012", " 123 "], "studies": ["9"]}`
and I need to TRIM leading and trailing spaces means the white space in front and the one after but not in the middle in case

Comment: The white space I added manually to show what I mean but can you do a favor if you can can you check this code https://pastebin.com/cYfWde8V and tell me if you think here anything is leading to having whitespace. lines from 185. Thank you

Comment: My supervisor sent me this msg 
but inside the JSONB we store strings. I don’t know how many users that are affected but a JSONB-content of type string can contain spaces even it the structure doesn’t. 

Example: 
“foo bar”
“foo bar “
“foobar “

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements_text` on the sites, `trim` each value, then `jsonb_agg`regate them back to an array.

```
UPDATE data
SET scope = jsonb_set(scope, '{sites}', (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(trim(site))
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(scope->'sites') AS s(site)
));
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=da39a64c90a623475bde00cb15df267a))</sup>

Since Postgres 14, you can also use more comfortable [subscripting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSONB-SUBSCRIPTING) to update json values, instead of `jsonb_set`:

```
UPDATE data
SET scope['sites'] = (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(trim(site))
  FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(scope['sites']) AS s(site)
);
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=f49420eeb6ab8caac2f3348ce77fd329))</sup>